# Fabric cryptogen tool generating incorrect certificate paths

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, x509certificate, docker-toolbox

When following the "Build Your First Network" example from Hyperledger Fabric, after the execution of the `./byfn.sh generate` the cryptogen tool is creating a various `config.yaml` files among the crypto-config directory, inside them are the `NodeOUs` especfications and the `Certificate` fields are defined as `cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem` or something like it depending on the organization. And when I run the `./byfn.sh up -l node`, errors like the one that follows gets printed on the terminal saying the file could not be found:

> 2019-12-05 16:31:55.085 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> INFO 002 Failed loading PeerOU certificate at ...

To make things clear, I'm running the Docker Toolbox on a Windows 10 Home edition with all the pre-requisites for the Hyperledger Fabric installed. Are there any solutions for this? Is it a bug because I'm running it on Windows 10 Home?

**Edit:**

A partial fix for this is manually switching `\ca` with `/ca` and then executing `./byfn.sh up`

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, actually Hyperledger Fabric is not supported on Windows, as far as I know.
You should run the dockers on Linux.

Comment: This is 100% true, while you can run Fabric on Windows, it's at your own risk, we do not recommend you do it, and do not provide any guarantee that it will work. We do not test any Windows paths in CI, nor does the fabric-test community.

Comment: This is bad news! Do you guys know if I would have problems if I used the CAs to generate the certificates running containers on Windows? Is the cryptogen tool actually the CA or it does their work when running the examples locally without one? Should the cryptogen tool be used in production?

Comment: Yes the cryptogen is like a CA and generates msp inside the crypto-config folder. Anyways I suggest to run the cryptogen tool again on Linux in order to do a clean generation

Comment: Thanks, @RicNtt! Do you know if the cryptogen tool is used in production? Or its just for learning and local development?

Comment: I am using it in production